# Anyone experience update records but only 1 row updated

Tags: sql-server

Is strange! I'm using sql server 2008 and when I perform an update in the query editor, it updates only the first row in that table, and I tried this command `SET rowcount 0`, but still only one row will get updated.

Anyone faced this before, the syntax is straight forward

```
UPDATE table
SET    status_one = 0
```

[image]

Comment: And you are sure there is more than only one record in that table? Can you reproduce the issue for us to see? (I.e. a simple table setup where the error also occurs...)

Comment: very sure, is more than 1 records. I not sure how to reproduce as i not sure what is going on. I can show you with image. Or could you let me know what is the step to troubleshoot?

Comment: Any possibility that the table has a horribly broken `instead of update` trigger defined on it?

Comment: Arhh... Thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever, there is trigger create by someone which i not sure what is the purpose. that helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen badly written triggers do (something) like this, for example:

```
create table User_Profile /* no Tbl, because **why**? */ (
  ID int IDENTITY(1,1) not null,
  tstatus int not null, /* no int, because again, **why** */
)
go
insert into User_Profile (tstatus) values (0)
go 8
create trigger T_User_Profile_U
on User_Profile
instead of update
as
    /* This is a broken trigger, for answering this question

    DO NOT COPY THIS TRIGGER CODE

    if you're trying to write an actual trigger */
declare @ID int
declare @status int
select @ID = ID,@status = tstatus from inserted
    /* The above was broken because despite me knowing to query
    inserted as a table, I've assumed that it contains one row

    whereas, in fact, it may contain 0, 1 or multiple rows.

    I'm not even guaranteed that the @ID and @status values
    will have been retrieved from the same row */

    /* Do important things */

update User_Profile set tstatus = @status where ID = @ID
```

And now, your query:

```
set rowcount 0
select tstatus from User_Profile

update User_Profile set tstatus = 1

select tstatus from User_Profile
```

Results:

```
tstatus
-------
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

and:

```
tstatus
-------
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
```